# use Swiper.js to do a circle carousel

Tags: swiper.js

It's my code
https://codepen.io/daylilystudio/pen/XWzVvVb

I make a circle carousel like Ferris wheel,
but after every 5 carousel,a group will fade in from right.
I don't want the group fade in suddenly.
How can I just fade in one slide every time？

```
var certifySwiper = new Swiper('#certify .swiper-container', {
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  centeredSlides: true,
  loop: true,
  autoplay: true,
  loopedSlides: 5,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    //clickable :true,
  },
  on: {
    progress: function(progress) {
      for (i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++) {
        var slide = this.slides.eq(i);
        var slideProgress = this.slides[i].progress;
        modify = 1;
        if (Math.abs(slideProgress) > 1) {
          modify = (Math.abs(slideProgress) - 1) * 0.3 + 1;
        }
        translate = slideProgress * modify * 260 + "px";
        scale = 1 - Math.abs(slideProgress) / 5;
        zIndex = 999 - Math.abs(Math.round(10 * slideProgress));
        slide.transform("translateX(" + translate + ") scale(" + scale + ")");
        slide.css("zIndex", zIndex);
        slide.css("opacity", 1);
        if (Math.abs(slideProgress) > 3) {
          slide.css("opacity", 0);
        }
      }
    },
    setTransition: function(transition) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++) {
        var slide = this.slides.eq(i);
        slide.transition(transition);
      }
    }
  }
})
```